# JButton won't compute when clicked

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

I'm bit newbie for these sort of GUI related areas. My problem is when I click the JButton mentioned in the below code, it doesn't compute. I tried several ways but no any luck.

Can any one give some idea on this?

**This is the driver:**

```
package project;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class Driver extends JFrame{
    private JTextField jtfDeposit = new JTextField("0.00");
    private JTextField jtfWithdraw = new JTextField("0.00");
    private JTextField jtfTransfer = new JTextField("0.00");
    private JTextField jtfCBalance = new JTextField("0.00");
    private JTextField jtfSBalance = new JTextField("0.00");

    private JButton jbtDeposit = new JButton("Deposit");
    private JButton jbtWithdraw = new JButton("Withdraw");
    private JButton jbtTransfer = new JButton("Transfer");

    String[] depositStrings = { "Checking", "Savings"};
    String[] withdrawStrings = { "Checking", "Savings"};
    String[] transferStrings = { "CHK* to SAVA*", "SAVA* to CHK*"};

    public Driver(){
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,4));
        p1.add(new JLabel("Deposit Into: "));
        p1.add(new JComboBox(depositStrings));
        p1.add(jtfDeposit);
        p1.add(jbtDeposit);

        p1.add(new JLabel("Withdraw From: "));
        p1.add(new JComboBox(withdrawStrings));
        p1.add(jtfWithdraw);
        p1.add(jbtWithdraw);

        p1.add(new JLabel("Transfer From: "));
        p1.add(new JComboBox(transferStrings));
        p1.add(jtfTransfer);
        p1.add(jbtTransfer);

        p1.setBorder(new TitledBorder("WELCOME TO THE BANK OF IS247"));

        JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,2));
        p2.add(new JLabel("Checking : "));
        p2.add(jtfCBalance);
        p2.add(new JLabel("Savings : "));
        p2.add(jtfSBalance);

        p2.setBorder(new TitledBorder("YOUR BALANCES"));

        add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        jbtDeposit.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        jbtWithdraw.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        jbtTransfer.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    }
    class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{
        Account cAcc = new CheckingAccount();
        Account sAcc = new SavingAccount();

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();
            switch (actionCommand){
                case "Deposit":
                    if("Deposit".equals(depositStrings[0])){
                        function(1);
                        break;
                    }else if("Deposit".equals(depositStrings[1])){
                        function(2);
                        break;
                    }
                case "Withdraw":
                    if("Withdraw".equals(withdrawStrings[0])){
                        function(3);
                        break;
                    }else if("Withdraw".equals(withdrawStrings[1])){
                        function(4);
                        break;
                    }
                case "Transfer":
                    if("Transfer".equals(transferStrings[0])){
                        function(5);
                        break;
                    }else if("Transfer".equals(transferStrings[1])){
                        function(6);
                    }
            }
        }
        private void function(int num){
            double dAmount = new Double(jtfDeposit.getText().trim()).doubleValue();
            double wAmount = new Double(jtfWithdraw.getText().trim()).doubleValue();
            double tAmount = new Double(jtfTransfer.getText().trim()).doubleValue();
            double cAmount = cAcc.getBalance();
            double sAmount = sAcc.getBalance();

            switch (num){
                case 1:
                    cAmount = cAcc.getDeposit(dAmount);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    sAmount = sAcc.getDeposit(dAmount);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    cAmount = cAcc.getWithdrawal(wAmount);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    sAmount = sAcc.getWithdrawal(wAmount);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    cAmount = cAcc.getTransfer(tAmount);
                    sAmount = sAcc.getDeposit(tAmount);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    sAmount = sAcc.getTransfer(tAmount);
                    cAmount = cAcc.getDeposit(tAmount);
                    break;
            }
            jtfCBalance.setText(String.valueOf(cAmount));
            jtfSBalance.setText(String.valueOf(sAmount));
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Driver frame = new Driver();
        frame.setTitle("Bank of IS247");
        frame.setSize(500,200);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**This is the parent class:**

```
package project;

public abstract class Account{
    public abstract double getBalance();
    public abstract double getDeposit(double amount);
    public abstract double getWithdrawal(double amount);
    public abstract double getTransfer(double amount);
}
```

Sub-class:

```
package project;

public class CheckingAccount extends Account{
    double balance = 1000.00;
    double deposit;
    double withdrawal;
    double transfer;

    public CheckingAccount(){
        //no-arg constructor
    }
    public CheckingAccount(double balance, double deposit, double withdrawal,
            double transfer){
        this.balance = balance;
        this.deposit = deposit;
        this.withdrawal = withdrawal;
        this.transfer = transfer;
    }
    @Override
    public double getBalance(){
        return balance;
    }
    @Override
    public double getDeposit(double deposit){
        balance += deposit;
        return balance;
    }
    @Override
    public double getWithdrawal(double withdrawal){
        balance -= withdrawal;
        return balance;
    }
    @Override
    public double getTransfer(double transfer){
        balance = getWithdrawal(transfer);
        return balance;
    }
}
```

**Sub-class:**

```
package project;

public class SavingAccount extends Account{
    double balance = 4500.00;
    double deposit;
    double withdrawal;
    double transfer;

    public SavingAccount(){
        //no-arg constructor
    }
    public SavingAccount(double balance, double deposit, double withdrawal,
            double transfer){
        this.balance = balance;
        this.deposit = deposit;
        this.withdrawal = withdrawal;
        this.transfer = transfer;
    }
    @Override
    public double getBalance(){
        return balance;
    }
    @Override
    public double getDeposit(double deposit){
        balance += deposit;
        return balance;
    }
    @Override
    public double getWithdrawal(double withdrawal){
        balance -= withdrawal;
        return balance;
    }
    @Override
    public double getTransfer(double transfer){
        balance = getWithdrawal(transfer);
        return balance;
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: *"JButton won't compute when clicked"*  Which `JButton` of the 3 declared in that source are you referring to?  No, on 2nd thoughts, post an MCVE with only one button..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple of problems.

1. I added a jtfCombo member variable. You need this reference so you can access the value in the combo box (Checking, Savings).
2. In actionPerformed(), you should use jtfCombo to get the selectedItem. Then you can decide which function to do.
3. You need a break; statement as the last statement in each of your cases.

Here's the updated code. I only made the changes for the deposit button. I have not checked your calculations, but it is updating now. Look for /* NEW */ for additions/changes:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class Driver extends JFrame{
    private JTextField jtfDeposit = new JTextField("0.00");
    private JTextField jtfWithdraw = new JTextField("0.00");
    private JTextField jtfTransfer = new JTextField("0.00");
    private JTextField jtfCBalance = new JTextField("0.00");
    private JTextField jtfSBalance = new JTextField("0.00");
    private JComboBox jtfCombo = null; /* NEW */

    private JButton jbtDeposit = new JButton("Deposit");
    private JButton jbtWithdraw = new JButton("Withdraw");
    private JButton jbtTransfer = new JButton("Transfer");

    String[] depositStrings = { "Checking", "Savings"};
    String[] withdrawStrings = { "Checking", "Savings"};
    String[] transferStrings = { "CHK* to SAVA*", "SAVA* to CHK*"};

    public Driver(){
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,4));
        p1.add(new JLabel("Deposit Into: "));

        jtfCombo = new JComboBox(depositStrings); /* NEW */
        p1.add(jtfCombo); /* NEW */
        p1.add(jtfDeposit);
        p1.add(jbtDeposit);

        p1.add(new JLabel("Withdraw From: "));
        p1.add(new JComboBox(withdrawStrings));
        p1.add(jtfWithdraw);
        p1.add(jbtWithdraw);

        p1.add(new JLabel("Transfer From: "));
        p1.add(new JComboBox(transferStrings));
        p1.add(jtfTransfer);
        p1.add(jbtTransfer);

        p1.setBorder(new TitledBorder("WELCOME TO THE BANK OF IS247"));

        JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,2));
        p2.add(new JLabel("Checking : "));
        p2.add(jtfCBalance);
        p2.add(new JLabel("Savings : "));
        p2.add(jtfSBalance);

        p2.setBorder(new TitledBorder("YOUR BALANCES"));

        add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        jbtDeposit.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        jbtWithdraw.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        jbtTransfer.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    }
    class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{
        Account cAcc = new CheckingAccount();
        Account sAcc = new SavingAccount();

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();
            switch (actionCommand){
            case "Deposit":
                if(jtfCombo.getSelectedItem().equals(depositStrings[0])){ /* NEW */
                    System.out.println("depositing to checking..."); /* NEW */
                    function(1);
                    break;
                }else if(jtfCombo.getSelectedItem().equals(depositStrings[1])){
                    System.out.println("depositing to savings..."); /* NEW */
                    function(2);
                    break;
                }
                break; /* NEW */
            case "Withdraw":
                if("Withdraw".equals(withdrawStrings[0])){
                    function(3);
                    break;
                }else if("Withdraw".equals(withdrawStrings[1])){
                    function(4);
                    break;
                }
                break; /* NEW */
            case "Transfer":
                if("Transfer".equals(transferStrings[0])){
                    function(5);
                    break;
                }else if("Transfer".equals(transferStrings[1])){
                    function(6);
                }
                break; /* NEW */
            }
        }
        private void function(int num){
            double dAmount = new Double(jtfDeposit.getText().trim()).doubleValue();
            double wAmount = new Double(jtfWithdraw.getText().trim()).doubleValue();
            double tAmount = new Double(jtfTransfer.getText().trim()).doubleValue();
            double cAmount = cAcc.getBalance();
            double sAmount = sAcc.getBalance();

            switch (num){
            case 1:
                cAmount = cAcc.getDeposit(dAmount);
                break;
            case 2:
                sAmount = sAcc.getDeposit(dAmount);
                break;
            case 3:
                cAmount = cAcc.getWithdrawal(wAmount);
                break;
            case 4:
                sAmount = sAcc.getWithdrawal(wAmount);
                break;
            case 5:
                cAmount = cAcc.getTransfer(tAmount);
                sAmount = sAcc.getDeposit(tAmount);
                break;
            case 6:
                sAmount = sAcc.getTransfer(tAmount);
                cAmount = cAcc.getDeposit(tAmount);
                break;
            }
            jtfCBalance.setText(String.valueOf(cAmount));
            jtfSBalance.setText(String.valueOf(sAmount));
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Driver frame = new Driver();
        frame.setTitle("Bank of IS247");
        frame.setSize(500,200);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a logic error, you set `depositStrings` to `{"Checking", "Savings"}` and they never change, but your checking to see if either of these `String`s match `Deposit`...

```
if ("Deposit".equals(depositStrings[0])) {
    function(1);
    break;
} else if ("Deposit".equals(depositStrings[1])) {
    function(2);
    break;
}
```

I assume they are suppose to match some kind of "account".  I also so assume this is the problem for the other cases...